# How can I customize the order/position in which TreeNodes are displayed in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview, position

I have: Parent-Child data with 4 hierarchy levels: 1 System, 2 Subsystem, 3 Unit, 4 Component
My problem (see picture): TreeView displays a Component, which is appended to the root node like Comp2.
My goal: DISPLAY all nodes in their correspondent "column" (e.g. Comp3).
I tried all indenting, spacing, padding, but nothing worked.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an itemtemplate for the Nodes, give them a width and they will be displayed exactly where you want them.

This code is for WPF, but I think there should be no big difference:

First, provide an ItemTemplate for your NodeViewModels, including a HierachicalDataTemplate

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="item" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource notSelectedItemTemplate}" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="item" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource selectedItemTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Second, provide a DataTemplate for your Nodes:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="selectedItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}">
    <Grid Height="Auto" TextElement.Foreground="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="----" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, I had two DataTemplates because I had a different one for selected nodes. For your case that should not be necessary, so just ignore the "notSelectedItemTemplate" and remove it.

Comment: To use an item template for the nodes is a good idea. But it is indeed a bit different with webforms. Can you translate your code, so that it works for a webforms TreeView control? ;)